# Is there a method for getting the results from the JSON-file?

Tags: java, json, google-maps

In the following code the "results", "geometry", "location", "lat" and "lng" are hardcoded.

The problem is, if Google changes some of those words my code won't work anymore. So my question is: is there a method in the Google maps API or the JSON library which solves my problem?

```
private Location getCoordinates(Location l, JSONObject json) {
        try {
            JSONArray jsonObject1 = (JSONArray) json.get("results");
            JSONObject jsonObject2 = (JSONObject)jsonObject1.get(0);
            JSONObject jsonObject3 = (JSONObject)jsonObject2.get("geometry");
            JSONObject location = (JSONObject) jsonObject3.get("location");

             l.setLat(Double.parseDouble(location.get("lat").toString()));
             l.setLon(Double.parseDouble(location.get("lng").toString()));

             return l;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Country or zip not found.");
        }

    }
```

Comment: I doubt they will change those wordings. I mean, I don't see a reason why they would

Comment: I also doubt it but it would be nice because when they change it I don't have to change the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Google client lib](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/webservices/client-library). Then you might get the coordinates like this.

```
    GeoApiContext context = new GeoApiContext().setApiKey("API_KEY");
    GeocodingResult[] results =  GeocodingApi.geocode(context,
            "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway Mountain View, CA 94043").await();
    for (GeocodingResult result : results) {
        System.out.println("LAT: " + result.geometry.location.lat);
        System.out.println("LNG: " + result.geometry.location.lng);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks I'm going to try this but I have one more question: am I able to limit the search to a specific country and ZIP code like this: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=&components=country:CA|postal_code:494043

Comment: I just realized that my link doesn't work... however the last part of the URL is important...

Comment: Yes. There is a filter. http://googlemaps.github.io/google-maps-services-java/v0.1.7/javadoc/com/google/maps/GeocodingApi.ComponentFilter.html